# Como setar posição de um cursor no Onchanged de uma Customview numa ListView?

Tags: java, android, listview, posição-do-cursor

Estou usando uma *customview* chamada [android-spinnerwheel](https://github.com/ai212983/android-spinnerwheel). Inseri ela numa *listview* ligada a um `CursorAdapter`. Se uso o `OnitemClickListener` da ListView, o cursor vai à posição correspondente da lista e fica tudo lindo... mas, se uso o `onChanged` desta *view* para atualizar um *hashmap* com o valor desta *customview* correspondente à chave do registro no cursor, como o cursor não altera seu ponteiro... e me retorna a chave errada.

No `CursorAdapter` ficou assim:

```
public class AdapterlistaPessoapub extends CursorAdapter {... 

public void BindView (View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {... 

SpinQtde.addChangingListener (new OnWheelChangedListener () 
{
@ Override 
public void onChanged (AbstractWheel wheel, int oldValue, int newValue) {

PessoapubActivity.items.put(getCursor().getInt(getCursor().getColumnIndex(constants.FPESSOAPUB_CODPUBLICACAO)), newValue); 

Log.i (GetCursor () getString (GetCursor () getColumnIndex (constants.FvPESSOAPUB_NOMEPUBLICACAO)) + "", "New value:.." + NewValue); 

} 
});
```

O logcat me retorna o registro errado.

Como forçar o cursor ir para a posição correta ao executar este `Onchanged`, de preferência sem "tags"?

Comment: o onChanged de qual View? Sem o código fica complicado.

Comment: "Estou usando uma customview chamada android-spinnerwheel."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esta forma de acessar o cursor é imprevisível...basicamente você acessa a posição qualquer que o cursor esteja naquele momento. Por exemplo, quando o momento do "**onChange**" acontece, o seu cursor pode está apontando para a posição referente ao último elemento da lista, mas você espera que ele seja correspondente ao da posição da View que você adicionou o listener.

Para garantir isso, vc usar o método [moveToPosition](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#moveToPosition%28int%29) para ir para a posição daquela view...recomendo que você volte para a posição anterior após usar. Para saber que posição, você pode setar a posição como "**tag**" da Wheel view que você deu inflate, assim quando o método **onChange**() for chamado você poderá acessar através do **wheel.getTag()**